# Непонятный тип ошибки int в python, первый раз такое, что нигде не нашел решения

Tags: python, int

Вот код:

```
for n in range(1, 1000):
    a = bin(n)[2:]
    c = sum(int(i) for i in a)
    if c % 2 == 0:
        c = str(c) +'00'
    else:
        c = str(c) + '11'
    if int(c, 2) > 114:
        print(d)
```

Появляется следующая ошибка: `if int(c, 2) > 114: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 2: '200'`
В чем может быть дело? Долго проверял, искал проблему, но так и не нашел.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Второй аргумент функции `int` - основание системы исчисления, а число `200` - не двоичное.